# VB.NET grab a section of an image and magnify it in anoter picturebox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

In vb.net when i click an image in a picturebox I am truing to capture the mouse position and populate a second picturebox with a zoomed in section of the image in picturebox 1.

The code seems to be working ... kind of ... It grabs a section of the image in picturebox 1 ... but not the section i click on.

```
 Private Function magnify(ByVal position As Point)
    vert2.Clear()
    horz2.Clear()

    Dim img As New Bitmap(preciseBox.Width, preciseBox.Height)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    Dim src As New Rectangle(position.X - 50, position.Y - 50, 100, 100)
    Dim dest As New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height)

    Try
        gr.DrawImage(xrayBox.Image, dest, src, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        img = New Bitmap(img, img.Width, img.Height)
        preciseBox.Image = img

        'Draws the crosshair on the magnify box
        vert2.Add(New Point(img.Width / 2, 0))
        vert2.Add(New Point(img.Width / 2, img.Height))
        horz2.Add(New Point(0, img.Height / 2))
        horz2.Add(New Point(img.Width, img.Height / 2))

        draw2 = True
        preciseBox.Invalidate()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return 0
End Function
```

Picturebox1 Size (at runtime) : Width 646px Height 687px
Picturebox1.Image Size (at runtime): Width 646px Height 484px
Picturebox2 Size (at runtime): Width 370px Height 230px

Comment: You are forgetting to pay attention to PictureBox.SizeMode.  That requires a bunch more code that maps the position to the pixel in the image.

Comment: @HansPassant Picturebox 1 and 2 are both in normal SizeMode. And before the image gets put into the picturebox I re-size it so that it fits, fills the space (either horizontally or vertically) and retains its scale. In this case I didnt think I should need to remap since the pixel in the Picturebox should match the position of the pixel in the image. I am adding the sizes of everything as i go through the debugger.

Comment: The empty Catch block is swallowing all possible errors. Just delete it. It serves no purpose except making debugging difficult.

Comment: I appreciate the advice about the catch block. Truth is I just hadn't added the logic to it yet. The issue here is that I don't seem to be throwing errors. I am actually getting an area back just not the area that I click on.